# Python/Selenium - Not able to select element by class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve all the usernames of the people who replied to a specific tweet.
The specific tweet is the [following](https://twitter.com/JustYGami/status/1637949323651723264) but from what I've seen it should work on any tweet.

**HTML:**

[image: tweet html]

**The code I used to try retrieving the usernames:**
As you can see I'm trying to retrieve the href where the username of the user who replied is stored via the class name.

```
TwitterClass = 'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l'

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

users = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,TwitterClass)
UserList= [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in users]
        
print(UserList)

#Out: []
```

Although I've selected the class name when i run this code I end up getting an empty list.

I haven't used selenium in a while and I'm still new to it but I've been searching posts on StackOverflow that might help and none seems to work I've also used a similar code for another project and it worked.

Can somebody help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: You can also try using the full XPATH instead of the class name.

Comment: @CocaColaCoder maybe that wouldn't be the best option since all usernames from people who replied have the same class name but not the same xpath/full xpath. If i can't solve the current problem thought i might try it, thanks.

Comment: @Unmitigated I just tried it (I edited the post) and that seems to solve the error but i still get an empty list, the problem seems to be that for some reason i can't detect any of the elements with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitespace in between each words in the `class` attribute `css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l` is the reason your code is not working and is returning empty list. Whitespace refers to more than one class. So, `By.CLASS_NAME` locator will not work. You can either use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.XPATH` as below:

Change the below line:

```
users = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,TwitterClass)
```

To:

```
users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l')]")
```

**Working code:**

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/JustYGami/status/1637949323651723264")
# TwitterClass = 'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l'
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l')]")
UserList = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in users]
print(UserList)
```

**Console output:**

```
['https://twitter.com/JustYGami', 'https://twitter.com/JustYGami']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Note:** This code will not guarantee to return all the usernames who replied which you are after. This will only return the list of users which are visible when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it does work now! However, you are right, I need to find a better way to get the users that reply since this won't return all users.